# org.hibernate.StaleStateException:Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: java

When I am trying to update key fields in to database this problem comes also using session.flush() and session.clear() methods.

Bean.java

```
SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session s = sf.openSession();
        Criteria crit3=s.createCriteria(RoleTable.class);
        roledata=crit3.list();
        for(RoleTable rt:roledata){
        Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
        RoleTable rot=new RoleTable();
        rot.setSno(1);
        rot.setObtype(rt.getObtype());
        rot.setObid(rt.getObid());
        rot.setText(rt.getText());
        rot.setSdat(rt.getSdat());
        rot.setEdat(rt.getEdat());
        rot.setUpdate(rt.isUpdate());
        rot.setCreate(rt.isCreate());
        rot.setDelete(rt.isDelete());
        rot.setRead(rt.isRead());
        s.update(rot);
        s.flush();
        s.clear();
        tx.commit();

        }
        s.close();
        sf.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you commit the transaction after flushing the session, change sequence of it like below:

```
tx.commit();  
s.flush();
s.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are updating an existing RoleTable (I guess you just want to update the Sno field).
You do not need create a new RoleTable. Just edit the one from the list (the rt instance)